# Woocommerce Tax always including tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax

I am using a table rate shipping option.
I tested two plugins so far, but for both plugins woocommerce seems to calculate the tax wrong.

## 1: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/table-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce/

## 2: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-easy-table-rate-shipping/

The problem is, that we are using the option "**shipping tax based on cart items**"

So I am entering in the table the shipping cost excluding tax.

For example (correct calculation):
*Shipping to netherlands* 13,99 €
For books the tax (7%) should  be added on top, *so total*: 14,97€ for shipping.

Woocommerce seems to calculate it differently:
Shipping to netherlands 13,99 € including tax.

*So total* is 13,99 € which is incorrect.
the order shows *13,07€ shipping and 0,92€ tax* on shipping.

I cant seem to find an option to give woocommerce the information that given shipping cost are entered exclusive tax.

Does anyone know how to correct the problem?
Because we cannot enter shipping costs including tax, because we have different tax classes on our products.

Comment: yes you can configure tax like that... check your tax settings.

Comment: @alice I check all neccessary information. The Shipping Costs are Taxable, I entered items without tax. But changing those, does not seem to help.

Comment: can I have a look at you admin panel ?

Answer (score 0):

Talking to the developer of the germanizer plugin, which was interfering with the shipping rates, we found a solution.

Problem was, the Germanizer plugin, calculates shipping according to the pre-tax values not the net vaues.

thats why the shipping cost was always wrong.

Deactivating it, helped. Or setting the pre-tax shipping inside the table rate plugin helps aswell.